# Regular expressions in C# to detect more than one space between words

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to use regular expressions in C# to validate a TextBox. I need to add this role in ValidationExpress for a Validation Control in ASP.NET. Regular expressions should not allow this:

- more that ONE space between words
- considering also beginning and end of the string

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to use regex or not?

Comment: @GlbboK - you never NEED to use anything, a valid solution is a valid solution, you can't prejudge what the most appropriate solution will be (even though imho, regex is the appropriate solution here).

Comment: You can always use a custom validation function.

Comment: @astandar - good call :)

Comment: @annajata - It may be homework, a programming tutorials, a supervisor not amenable to reason, or something else of course.

Comment: ASP Validation Control is a good reason - you can avoid regex with a custom control, but it's more effort for debatable gain. @GlbboK - can't tell if you want a double space at start/end to be valid or invalid?

Comment: NO at start/end should NOT be valid

Comment: im a beginner so what i write in field ValidationExpression for my ASP Validation Control????? thanks guys

Comment: Can you give examples of valid and invalid inputs? Please use `-` instead of spaces, so we can see them `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are limited to validating a string, try the following pattern ([example](http://www.rubular.com/r/3W4rO1mCsJ)):

```
^[ ]?([^ ]+[ ])*[^ ]*$
```

It doesn't allow strings with two spaces anywhere in the string. This pattern ignores tabs and newlines, by the way. I've picked `[ ]` so you can see the spaces, but a simple space is the same. `\s` may not be right for you. For one, it might match a windows new line, `\r\n`.

Similarly, you can use a negative lookahead ([example](http://www.rubular.com/r/eRJVsajjvK)):

```
^(?!.*[ ]{2})
```

If you're using a client side validator you need to match from start to end, so use the pattern `(?!.*[ ]{2}).*`. It implicitly adds `^...$` around your pattern.
Either way, consider using a custom validator and writing a simple line of code to negate searching for two spaces. Here's how it's done. First, [look at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx) add a JavaScript function to your page:

```
function noTwoSpaces(source, arguments) {
    arguments.IsValid = (arguments.Value.indexOf('  ') == -1);
}
```

Next, add the `CustomValidator` control to use it:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage=":-(" 
    ClientValidationFunction="noTwoSpaces"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

And that's it. Much easier than an elusive regex.

Answer (score 4):

No need for regexps.

```
if (string.StartsWith(" ") || string.EndsWith(" ") || string.Contains("  ")) throw...
```

Comment: except this doesn't account for non-breaking spaces and tabs. not sure if it matters though.

Comment: And I mean it, unless you really have a specific need for a regexp, don't use it, the code I wrote performs much better and is much easier to understand. Why do you want to make it perform worse and make it more complex than actually needed?

Comment: @fejesjoco - I'd debate that was any easier to understand than regex, and certainly not a performance concern until proven otherwise - especially considering you're invoking three string search methods (and wouldn't `Contains()` be sufficient by itself?)

Comment: @annakata: not 3, just one string search, the contains() call. And it is necessary, because a regexp would have to look through the string, too, but a regexp has other overheads. Starts/EndsWith don't search the whole string, so again, it performs better.

Comment: @fejosjoco - and a startswith and an endswith... and until you prove that the relative performance is A). a problem and B). actually better (regex can also bail as soon as it finds a match) then you're guilty of premature micro-optimisation.

Comment: @annakata: first of all, the first call to a regexp will compile the regexp and it will be about ten times slower. after that, it will be a few percent slower. and it's not even the actual performance gain, it's the ATTITUDE that counts: don't use regexp's when they are absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @fejesjoco - This is nonsensical. 10 times *very little indeed* is still *very little indeed*, and I frankly doubt your numbers. Considering the OPs requirement (a validation control) I also think it's less appropriate to create a custom control with logic in the code-behind than to use an existing tool with a very simple expression in the mark up. I agree that it's the attitude that counts - don't arbitrarily discard tools.

Comment: Seems like the best approach. If `\s` is needed and newlines should be considered the matter becomes more difficult - `\s{2}` would match a windows new line - `\r\n`. Easy to get around, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want:

```
 if (myText.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length != 
     myText.Split(" ").Length)
 {
    //String contains multiple spaces
 }
```

As you've now said you DO want regexes I'd use

```
 @"\s\s+"
```

to match two or more whitespaces or:

```
 @"\ \ +"
```

to match two or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

var rex = new Regex(@"\s{2,}");

Edit: Didn't see the start/end of the string.

```
        string poo = "a b";
        string poo1 = "a  b";
        string poo2 = "a   b";
        string poo3 = "a    b";
        string poo4 = " a  b";
        string poo5 = "a   b ";
        string poo6 = " a    b ";
        string poo7 = " a b ";
        var rex = new Regex(@"^\s{0}.\s{0,1}.\s{0}$");

        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo1));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo2));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo3));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo4));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo5));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo6));
        Console.WriteLine(rex.IsMatch(poo7));
```

This returns:

```
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

Since the only valid string is the first one.

Comment: A single space at start/end is valid, so your first regex is good, but the second one is nonsense. What is `\s{0}` supposed to mean? Also, you can write `?` instead of `{0,1}`. And your second regex will fail to validate a string of length 1.

Comment: If the string starts or ends with a space, it will not match the regex, the string is invalid...I ran the regex against the examples above and showed the result. Will look at value of 1 length tho.

Comment: Sorry Phill, but this answer is extremely wrong. First,  `{0}` makes no sense. Next, it has a **maximal length of 3 letters**: `.\s.`. Finally, a `.` might match a space anyway, so I'm not sure what you've achieved (it will match 3 spaces, for example).

Comment: @Kobi - The {0} makes perfect sense, 0 whitespace at the start and end of the string. It currently has a max length of two, not three. And it wont match 3 spaces as my examples showed. I'm checking for a string with no start/end space, and no more than 1 space in the string. Theres a different issue with the regex tho that you haven't seen.

Comment: What is the difference between `\s{0}abc` and `abc`?

Comment: What @Kobi meant was that it matches a string consisting *entirely* of three spaces.  `^\s{0}.\s{0,1}.\s{0}$` matches a string that's two or three characters long; if it's three characters, the middle one must be whitespace.  `\s{0}` does not mean *not a whitespace character* -- in fact, it doesn't mean *anything*; it just takes up space.  (`{0}` should be a syntax error IMO.  All it does is lead people astray when they assume it serves a useful purpose.  `{1}` is almost as bad, but at least it *does* something.)

Comment: Ok, I'm aware that there's an issue with it when it validates anything in the middle like 'a a  a', this wont validate. I've been trying to write this in javascript tho since the OP needs it for a validation control and I can't work out how to do it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, use this:

```
 {2,}
```

(NB: There is a space before the brackets).

Comment: Explain the -1. The OP specifically asked for a regex solution, and I gave it to him.

Comment: 0 is not a space, but ' ' is, and it's Length, not Length(), and OP also asked for starting and ending spaces

Comment: @fejesjoco - I can't see 0 or Length here, and a regex will match anywhere in the string (or this one will anyway) though I beleive you should be writing \s not ' '

Comment: @annakata: there used to be a C# code with string.Length() and str[x] == 0

Comment: @fejesjoco you are commenting and probably downvoting on a wrong answer. There's no history of edits associated with this answer proving you words.

Comment: @Ondrej it must have been edited because it was here and now it's not.

Comment: Are you talking about the answer from Dean Chalk which uses 'Length'? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525348/regular-expressions-in-c-to-detect-more-than-one-space-between-words/4525366#4525366

Comment: @Phill: no, i'm sure it was this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without regex, but imho it's less obvious to not use regex:

`\s{2,}` or `\s\s+` if .NET doesn't support the match-min-max syntax (I don't recall).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
string s = " tada  bling zap  ";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\s\s+");
MatchCollection m = reg.Matches(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

For beginning and ending no white spaces `^[^\s](.*\s.*)+[^\s]$`

`Mary bought a shoe` match

`MarySqeezeIntoAshoe` no match